# Can't resolve git conflicts due to policy using Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

So I have a master branch and a development branch; both of them are locked such that changes to the branches can only be made via pull request. I want to merge some changes from development into master on the server, and I created a pull request to do so. However there were conflicts, so I did the merge manually locally and tried to push the changes to the server. I can't do this due to the policy of requiring a pull request! Is there any other way I can get the conflicts resolved without violating the policy? All I can think of now is to abandon the pull request and create a new one, but I'm not sure if that would even do what I need - there's no way to actually resolve the conflicts that I'm aware of without a local merge, and there's no way to get the resolved changes into the master branch that I'm aware of without pushing to master, which is forbidden by policy - help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with my boss about this last night and he figured out how to do it:

1) pulled both master and development

2) merged from master into development locally

3) resolved conflicts

4) created and completed pull request

5) pulled development

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me - I would have done it sooner but for some reason I'm not allowed to accept my own answer until a few days have passed, and it slipped my mind!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setup, you are supposed to get changes into **develop** from **feature/somefeature** branches via **PR**, correct? And you get changes from **develop** into **master** using another **PR** (by convention as branch policies do not define relationships between specific branches).

#### Consider your Conflict Resolution to be a "Feature"

Abandon your current **PR** as it's busted w/o a force push. Creating a new **feature/ConflictResolution** branch based on current **develop**. Then pull latest **master** on localhost and them merge **master** => **feature/ConflictResolution**. This should give you the same conflicts seen in the **PR** between develop and master. Resolve those conflicts and push to the remote **feature/ConflictResolution** to initiate a new PR into develop, and then into master.

#### OR: Put your *conflictResolution* directly into *master* via PR

This is basically the same as the previous option, except you are creating a PR between the **conflictResolution** branch and **master**. I think this would remove any changes you need to PR between **develop** and **master**, so the existing PR might "go away" after you tell it to re-merge.

#### ULTIMATE OR: Stop using merge hell branch strategies

You still want to use a trunk based strategy, and that's fine, but do away with the locked develop branch convention. Keep the policy on master, make sure it is required, add a build validation on it, and call it good. This forces any changes going into master to use a PR and get a **Restore >> Build >> Test** gate build executed. If you have a rigid deployment authoring process, use tags to mark those ceremonial milestones in history.

This is a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykZbBD-CmP8) about some of the strategies and how they have matured and gained trust over time.

Comment: I tried your first solution with a branch "conflictResolution". After I merged that into dev I still had the same conflicts when trying to merge to master. I could however merge the conflict resolution branch into master. I am simply trying to figure out the cause why option 1 is not working. Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is raised when creating the PR against develop, right? I guess the best you can do is transform that merge into a single revision (if possible for you) on top of development... and then you can create the PR from that.

So..... you have already merged with develop, right?

```
git reset --soft develop # put all changes related to your PR into the index, ready to commit
git commit -m "My PR changes"
```

Now, all your changes after solving all conflicts are in a single revision after develop (develop hasn't moved). Push that branch (and that should update the PR on its own and allow you to merge).

Comment: No, there is no PR against development; the pull request is from development to master. It got broken because I had previously created a second pull request from a separate branch to master just to change the version number and a few things like that; I should have completed the PR from development first, before completing the one from the version number branch.

Comment: Then revert the change on master and bring stuff over from development, otherwise conflict will remain there and you will be stuck (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I have permission to revert changes on master; I'll have to talk this over with my boss I guess since he's in charge of the repo!

Comment: What do you mean? How were you are to put changes in master without going through development first? Through a PR? Then create another PR with a change that _reverts_ those changes in master that are busting you (like, `git revert the-revision-i-want-to-revert`, push the change into a branch, create a PR, merge into master).

Comment: There's no policy preventing pull requests from branches other than development into master; it's just a convention that most changes would go through development first. I guess a revert commit might work!

Comment: @ekolis there's no such thing as a branch policy that is only enforced between two specific branches. Branch policies are protecting a given branch from all other branches.

Answer (score 0):

The correct process is that you should merge **master** branch to your **development** branch, then commit and push changes to **development** branch, then create Pull Request to merge changes to **Master**.

There is extension that can resolve conflict **online** without needing to do it locally.

[Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)